# How to add labels following the moving circle in the animation?

Tags: matlab, animation, text, 3d, label

I read some related discussion:

[How to add dynamic data labels inside of .avi animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663021/how-to-add-dynamic-data-labels-inside-of-avi-animation/28664975#28664975)

[Text Animation with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717775/text-animation-with-matlab?newreg=cecfbc23c69f48668c4e8f9c28968e3c)

These examples are much difficult than mine so I cannot quite understand how to solve my problem.

---

I made the following animation, I just want to

1. add the label "{E}" under the "center blue point"
2. add the label "{P}" near the "small blue circle", which rotate the "center blue point" and inside the "middle blue circle".
3. add the label "{S}" near the "small red *", which rotate the "big blue circle".

Of course labels {P} and {S} should closely follow each corresponding object.

How could I do that?
...

```
clear all;
close all;
clc


%% time specifications
stoptime = 8;
fs = 50;
dt = 1/fs;
t = (0:dt:stoptime)';

N = size(t,1); 
%% 
vx(:,1) = 0;vy(:,1) = 15;vz(:,1) = 0;
ux(:,1) = 0 ;uy(:,1) = 3 ;uz(:,1) = 0;

%% angular velocity
Ix = 3,5;
Iz = 1;
w = .1; % w_L
wp = ( (Ix-Iz)/Iz )*w*(2)^.5


%% 
for k = 2:N

vx(:,k) = cos(w*(k-1))*vx(:,1) - sin(w*(k-1))*vy(:,1) + 0*vz(:,1);
vy(:,k) = sin(w*(k-1))*vx(:,1) + cos(w*(k-1))*vy(:,1) + 0*vz(:,1);
vz(:,k) = 0*vx(:,k-1) + 0*vy(:,k-1) + 1*vz(:,k-1);

ux(:,k) = cos((w+wp)*(k-1))*ux(:,1) - sin((w+wp)*(k-1))*uy(:,1) + 0*uz(:,1) + vx(:,k);
uy(:,k) = sin((w+wp)*(k-1))*ux(:,1) + cos((w+wp)*(k-1))*uy(:,1) + 0*uz(:,1) + vy(:,k);
uz(:,k) = 0*ux(:,1) + 0*uy(:,1) + 1*uz(:,1) + vz(:,k);    




o = [0;0];
xline = [vx(:,k);o(1,1)];
yline = [vy(:,k);o(2,1)];
xline1 = [vx(:,k);ux(:,k)];
yline1 = [vy(:,k);uy(:,k)];

figure(1)
ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=15*cos(ang);
yp=15*sin(ang);  
xp1=3*cos(ang)+vx(:,k);
yp1=3*sin(ang)+vy(:,k);

plot(xp,yp,'c--'); hold on
plot(xp1,yp1); hold on
plot(0,0,'.'); hold on
plot(xline,yline); hold on 
plot(xline1,yline1); hold on 
plot(vx(:,k),vy(:,k),'bo');
plot(ux(:,k),uy(:,k),'r*'); hold on
axis([-25 25 -25 25]);
axis equal
axis manual
pause(.1);
hold off
end
```

[image]

Sorry, I have no idea to upload my animation video. That is just the picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `text` function.

```
tOff = [1,1];   %%% (text offset)
plot(xp,yp,'c--'); hold on
plot(xp1,yp1); 
plot(0,0,'.'); 
text (tOff, tOff, sprintf('(%d,%d)', 0, 0)); %%%
plot(xline,yline); 
plot(xline1,yline1); 
plot(vx(:,k),vy(:,k),'bo'); 
text (vx(:,k)+tOff,vy(:,k)+tOff, sprintf('(%1.3d,%1.3d)', vx(:,k),vy(:,k))); %%%
plot(ux(:,k),uy(:,k),'r*'); 
text (ux(:,k)+tOff,uy(:,k)+tOff, sprintf('(%1.3d,%1.3d)', vx(:,k),vy(:,k))); %%%
axis([-25 25 -25 25]);
axis equal
axis manual
pause(.1);
hold off
```

This is the same code as yours above, except with some additions, marked with `%%%`.
Also note, `hold on` only needs to be specified once, and will apply until `hold off` occurs (or the figure is destroyed). (I removed the superfluous `hold on` instructions in your code above).

[image]